# boot full half installed kernals

Tags: boot, package-management

I've only had Ubuntu for a couple of months so please be gentle as I'm a complete noob here. I'm getting the boot full warning that seems to have plagued many on here, but none of the answers seem to work. I have tried removing old kernels from the terminal and with synaptic. It seems as though many are half installed, but they cannot be repaired as there is no room; bit of a vicious circle. I hope this makes sense to someone.

Please help,

Matt

```
mitchell@mitchell-Inspiron-530:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-36-generic
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 5 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 808 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 216763 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic (4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic (4.2.0-34.39~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic (4.2.0-35.40~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.2.0-36-generic (4.2.0-36.42~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-36-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-36-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-36-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-36-generic (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached

Removing linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic (4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached

Errors were encountered while processing:
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)}
```

Ok not sure about how I edit this post; hopefully this info is what

> you asked for Phil.

```
mitchell@mitchell-Inspiron-530:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image pi 
linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic                         
4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP ii 
linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic                         
4.2.0-34.39~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP ii 
linux-image-4.2.0-35-generic                         
4.2.0-35.40~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP ii 
linux-image-4.2.0-36-generic                         
4.2.0-36.42~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP pi 
linux-image-4.2.0-38-generic                         
4.2.0-38.45~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP ii 
linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic                         
4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP ii 
linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic                         
4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP rH 
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic                   
4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP rH 
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic                   
4.2.0-34.39~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP rH 
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic                   
4.2.0-35.40~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP rH 
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-36-generic                   
4.2.0-36.42~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP ii 
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-38-generic                   
4.2.0-38.45~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP rH 
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic                   
4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP iF 
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic                   
4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1                                 amd64
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP iU 
linux-image-generic-lts-wily
                      4.2.0.42.34     
amd64        Generic Linux kernel image`

mitchell@mitchell-Inspiron-530:~$ ls -l /boot total 230705
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1312643 Feb 26 20:36 abi-4.2.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1312645 Mar 11 13:17 abi-4.2.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1313029 Mar 18 18:14 abi-4.2.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1313407 May 13 22:55 abi-4.2.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1313411 Jun  9 11:51 abi-4.2.0-38-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1313640 Jun 24 19:37 abi-4.2.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1313590 Jun 29 23:31 abi-4.2.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184896 Feb 26 20:36 config-4.2.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184896 Mar 11 13:17 config-4.2.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184896 Mar 18 18:14 config-4.2.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184896 May 13 22:55 config-4.2.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184897 Jun  9 11:51 config-4.2.0-38-generic
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184897 Jun 24 19:37 config-4.2.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184934 Jun 29 23:31 config-4.2.0-42-generic 
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 Jul 16 12:12 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3325217 Jul  5 17:58 initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20661169 Mar 13 13:08 initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20661076 Mar 14 17:44 initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20678829 Apr  9 18:35 initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21373450 Jun 19 13:36 initrd.img-4.2.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21372333 Jun 19 13:36 initrd.img-4.2.0-38-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21374089 Jul  5 17:58 initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21372772 Jul 15 18:17 initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Mar 13
11:13 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176500 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178176 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178680 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3757557 Feb 26 20:36 System.map-4.2.0-30-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3757656 Mar 11 13:17 System.map-4.2.0-34-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3758162 Mar 18 18:14 System.map-4.2.0-35-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3758996 May 13 22:55 System.map-4.2.0-36-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3759342 Jun  9 11:51 System.map-4.2.0-38-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3759492 Jun 24 19:37 System.map-4.2.0-41-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3760051 Jun 29 23:31 System.map-4.2.0-42-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6715312 Feb 26 20:36 vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6716080 Mar 11 13:17 vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6731856 Mar 18 18:14 vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6732816 May 13 22:55 vmlinuz-4.2.0-36-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6732272 Jun  9 11:51 vmlinuz-4.2.0-38-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6734768 Jun 24 19:37 vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6736496 Jun 29 23:31 vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic`

mitchell@mitchell-Inspiron-530:~$ df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev tmpfs
396M  1.5M  394M   1% /run /dev/dm-0       290G   50G  225G  19% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup none           
5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock none            2.0G   76K  2.0G   1% /run/shm none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user /dev/sda1    
236M  234M     0 100% /boot

mitchell@mitchell-Inspiron-530:~$ uname -r
4.2.0-42-generic`
```

Comment: please add the following information to your question: `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`, `ls -l /boot`, `df -h` and `uname -r`

Comment: can't you uninstall a big programme like chrome, firefox or libreoffice, fix the kernels and then reinstall the programme? EDIT: only works if /boot and /usr are on your root partition

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It's late here now, but i'll give it a go tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are affected by a [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1678187)  bug. Please login to launchpad.net and mark that you are affected, so that the bug will be marked as confirmed.

See also my [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/898499/21005) about similar issue and my answer to it.

See [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels) for general information about removing extra kernels.