# Why there is an update-initramfs error when removing a kernel by dpkg?

Tags: kernel, dpkg, initramfs, purge

I got the following output when removing a kernel by `dpkg --purge` :

```
Removing linux-headers-3.13.0-112-generic (3.13.0-112.159) ...
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic (3.13.0-112.159) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-112-generic
W: TMPDIR is mounted noexec, will not cache run scripts.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-112-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic (3.13.0-112.159) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-67-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-67-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-115-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-115-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-113-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-113-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
  No volume groups found
done
Purging configuration files for linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic (3.13.0-112.159) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic
```

Why does it run out of space even when purging? It is not an inode issue in this case.

Note: There are other questions where error happens during `dpkg --configure` or when installing a kernel. It is more understandable that system runs out of disk space then, but in this case I am purging a kernel - a linux-image-extra package to be specific - by `dpkg`. There is no dependency problem in this case. For example in [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/171209/21005) a solution could be to purge kernel packages directly by `dpkg`, but the issue of this question produces an error when doing so.

Comment: @ElderGeek this happens when purging by dpkg, not by configuring.

Comment: @ElderGeek : I agree with jarno, and don't think it is a duplicate, at least of the referenced dup. Readers should also know that jarno is very experienced with kernel removal / purging.

Comment: Dpkg should be using `/` for work files and not `/boot` as per discussion we had in AU General Chat room as I was defining `rmkernels` project scope. This is an interesting problem presented by @jarno.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix or it could use "/tmp" or whatever `mktemp` uses by default. I actually modified `update-initramfs` locally so that it works in this case.

Comment: @jarno The thing is when I first started planning the project I was thinking I read of problem where people couldn't purge because of no space left in `/boot` so the initial idea was to set file size of kernels images to 1 and then reclaim space in `/boot` before running `apt-get purge` but the idea was shot down by someone else as unnecessary. Now I'm thinking I should have stuck to the initial design....

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate of all those questions.

Comment: @fkraiem I claim my answer is useful for this question. Not that useful for the other questions you refer to.

Comment: @karel Thank you for your edit. This question is much improved due to your efforts.

Comment: @jarno Regarding [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/898499/why-there-is-an-update-initramfs-error-when-removing-a-kernel-by-dpkg#comment1408465_898499) Do you have swap enabled? AFAIK, tmpfs should be able to move pages to swap to free up space. The output of `df -h` and `free` might shed some light on the issue as well.

Comment: @ElderGeek I have swap enabled and /tmp mounted as tmpfs. The main thing is that /boot is not mounted in same point. The usual case when /boot is full is when /boot is in a separate partition.

Comment: @jarno Hence the duplicate flag

Comment: @ElderGeek I don't see what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56375/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-jarno).

Answer (score 6):

When purging a linux-image-extra package, post installation scripts are  run, since the main linux-image package of that kernel release may be left remaining in system: The respective initrd.img will be altered not to contain the extra's stuff; its size will decrease as a result of this process. However, the old initrd.img file is not removed in "/boot" and the new one is created beside it in "/boot" during this process, so there is a risk of running out of space.

The fix could be to create the new initrg.img file in different partition before replacing the old one by it in `update-initramfs`. So the `update-initramfs` script should be fixed.

A workaround would be to remove the respective versioned /boot/initrd.img file before running `dpkg --purge` for the linux-image-extra package. That could also be done by `sudo update-initramfs -d -k 3.13.0-112-generic` in this case, as the kernel I was removing was "3.13.0-112-generic".

Comment: The last paragraph doesn't really belong here, if you think there is a bug in how kernel removals are handled, file one on Launchpad.

Comment: @fkraiem I added a workaround.

Comment: @fkraiem it does not harm telling where the problem lies here.

Comment: @fkraiem There's nothing wrong with writing about a workaround to a problem that may occur frequently.

Comment: @fkraiem [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1678187) added.

Comment: @fkraiem can you confirm the bug?

Comment: @jarno I can confirm the behavior you describe, although I'm not sure I would personally consider it a bug.

Comment: @fkraiem Do you expect dpkg --purge to fail purging a linux-image-extra package due to running out of space at /boot.

Comment: @fkraiem I changed the report a bit.